# Are there free snorkeling sites in Cuba outside of Varadero and Cayos?

Tags: budget, cuba, diving

One of our favourite activities when travelling is diving. I've been reading about good snorkeling sites, but all require a tax to access to the beach or are located in the expensive touristic areas of Cuba (Varadero and Cayos). Are there any free snorkeling sites in Cuba?

Comment: May be I can reformulate the question: Are there any free snorkeling site excluding Varadero and Cayos?

Comment: Varadero's really not that expensive. The beach itself is free (go onto beach at Avenida 41). It's beautiful. (source: was there two months ago)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can answer my own question after travelling to Cuba.

All the places I visited were free of charge, including Varadero and other major spots like Guardalavaca. Before I visited Cuba I read that you have to pay for access to the beaches, but this information is outdated or false: you don't have to pay for access anywhere.

Interesting snorkeling sites I visited include:

- Coral beach: between Varadero and Matanzas. This was the best snorkeling site we visited.
- Guardalavaca: 100 meters off shore you can find a lot of colorful fish.
- Siboney beach: near Santiago. Good snorkeling if you are lucky (because that beach has some problems with algae).

Answer (score 2):

In late Feb 2018 I stayed in the village of Casilda just outside Trinidad (my hosts were Sergio y Lesly, a nice stay). There's a beach called Playa Ancon a short ride away by horse cart or if you can stand the heat, by bicycle. The first part of it is all-coral, sadly bleached, but you only have to step into the water to start seeing fishes. A delightful surprise. The bar will charge you 3CUC for a beach chair but then they leave you alone. I was there in late Feb 2018.

Answer (score 1):

Not exact answer to your question but there is snorkeling site in Playa Ancon - you need to pay 1 CUC for a bike parking, 10 CUC for boat which takes 2 km away from the shore and snorkeling equipment for 1-1.5h.